# Aircrack-NG fundamentals: is it possible to translate the `Data` field to bytes/kilobytes/megabytes?

Tags: aircrack-ng

This is a capture example of [Aircrack-NG](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/):

```
 CH  8 ][ Elapsed: 48 s ][ 2015-06-30 00:37 ][ disabled selection

 BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH ESSI

 DC:9F:DB:A6:E2:6E  -77  86      404      859    0   8  54e. OPN              Salo
```

As long as `#Data` field (supposedly transferred data captured) has a value of `859`, **how many bytes** are such number?

Answer (score 0):

Why not starting with some example **empirical measurements**?

Lets try with a 802.11b (rather old and relatively **slow**) network. My effective best throughtput in data transfer uses to be 1MB/seg for this network:

**Case 1**: Best scenario. Only one file.

```
Number of files:        1
Total transferred size: 37.060.608 bytes
Average size/file:  37.060.608 bytes
#Data captured:     41.478
Bytes/Data:     893,50
```

**Case 2**: Average scenario. A few files.

```
Number of files:        11
Total transferred size: 6.150.538 bytes
Average size/file:  ~500.000 byte
#Data captured:     10.772
Bytes/Data:     570,97
```

**Case 3**: Worst scenario. Lots of small (1 byte size) files.

```
Number of files:        10.000
Total transferred size: 10.000 bytes
Average size/file:  1 byte
#Data captured:     134.270
Bytes/Data:     0,07
```

So, **results vary widely** from nearly **1 MB/data** to an astonishing less than **1 byte/data** (LOL).

If I am not wrong, we can conclude that, without more info about the data being transferred, and knowing only the `#Data` field, **there is no practical way to know the correlation** between `Data` and `bytes` on the wireless traffic.
Maybe this conclussion could be true for cable networks too.